# Mahout Naive Bayes Model Unable to find cached files issue

Tags: java, classification, mahout

I have imported:

```
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.training.TrainNaiveBayesJob;
```

from the [Mahout-Core-0.9-job](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.9/org/apache/mahout/classifier/naivebayes/training/TrainNaiveBayesJob.java)

However when I try to call the following method:

```
String[] trainerArgs = {"-i", vectorsDirectory + "tfidf-vectors/",
                        "-o", modelDirectory,
                        "-l", labelIndex,
                        "-el", "-ow"};

TrainNaiveBayesJob thisTrainer = new TrainNaiveBayesJob();
thisTrainer.run(trainerArgs);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find cached files!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find cached files!
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil.getCachedFiles(HadoopUtil.java:300)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil.getSingleCachedFile(HadoopUtil.java:281)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.BayesUtils.readIndexFromCache(BayesUtils.java:146)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.training.IndexInstancesMapper.setup(IndexInstancesMapper.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Where exactly am I missing the point? Can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing the call to the NaiveBayes to:

`ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new TrainNaiveBayesJob(), trainerArgs);`

solved the issue.